# Subscripted value is neither array nor pointer error

Tags: arrays, pointers, struct, compiler-errors

**I have this in a header file (Variables.h):**

```
#ifndef VARIABLES_H
#define VARIABLES_H

#define NUM 99
#define BOOL 193
#define FLOAT 12

struct bools{
    char name[100];
    bool state;
}bool_dataPoints[BOOL];

struct floats{
    char name[100];
    float q;
}float_dataPoints[FLOAT];

struct nums{
    char name[100];
    unsigned int q;
}num_dataPoints[NUM];
```

...

**I'm trying to use this instruction (which is in a separate C file):**

```
#include "xc.h"
#include <stdbool.h>       
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include "Variables.h"
    
if(bool_dataPoints[147].state){//I_EStop
```

...

**But I'm getting this error for that 'if' line of code:**

```
error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the arguments in my prototype/ declaration did not match the arguments in my implementation. I was not including the argument datatypes.